# How to load 3d object from web server or url in vuforia unity 5.1?

Tags: unity-game-engine, load, vuforia

I want to load a 3D object from a URL to a `CloudRecoTarget`, anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify your intention more precise? I'm not sure if if get it.
Where is your problem and what kind of technology are you using (App, Server...)?

I guess you want to upload a 3D object, that you are downloading from somewhere of the web, to the Vuforia Cloud Database to create a Vuforia Marker that can be used in Unity for an AR application.
Usually you have a server that handles the communication between the app and the Vuforia API. Your server can simply add a target (your 3d object) to the cloud database and after analysing the target you can download the marker from Vuforia. That's the way I've done it.

Probably you can do this without a server using Unity and C# only. Have a look at the [Vuforia API](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Use-the-Vuforia-Web-Services-API.html) to write you own Vuforia Client in C#. Maybe there is a code snippet somewhere.